# Send php variable to Flash

Tags: php, flash

I am working on Flash,Php site.Currently the Flash Developer calles my page called createJPG.php and sends me an image data.I recieve this data and create JPG from the Data.

What i want is, when the Flash developer send me data he can show a loader and when create JPG process is complete he can hide the loader.For this i want to pass him variable with value 1 as soon as the CreateJPG process is complete...

How can i pass this varialbe ??

Comment: What have you tried, and what isn't working?  Can you show us some code, please?

Comment: I have tried this `$fName = "nuno";
$lname = "mira";
$age = 24;
// echo or print the variables
echo ("&fName=$fName&lName=$lName&age=$age&");` but no luck ...

Comment: This is just for dummy variable i can change it later once they are successfully received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use [External Interface](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/External+Interface) because you have loaded SWF and it in Running mode
by using [External InterFace](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/External+Interface) you can call Flex Method to pass value ck [Accessing JavaScript functions from Flex](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=passingarguments_4.html)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I am aware of is to use normal GET requests over your flash application.

something like

> "yourflashobject.swf?name=john&surname=doe"

you can request the createJPG.php from your flash app and then check the size of the request.

Not sure if you can see returned status ( like 200 OK, Error 404 etc ) from flash. Somebody please confirm.